# Handle JsonProcessingException when building response, but business logic already finished

Tags: java, rest, exception, jackson, embedded-jetty

I have jetty server, which does some logic, when it is finished, it creates a json string (using jackson) and sends it as a response. If there is an exception during the creation of the json, a JsonProcessingException is thrown. This exception bubbles up to an UncaughtErrorHandler (extends ErrorHandler in Jetty), which logs the exception and returns some failure message and status code 500.

This is just for a backend api.

The endpoint is not idempotent (it is a post endpoint), there are changes to the state of the application (ie database) when endpoint is hit and logic applied.

Now if JsonProcessingException occurs, the user will get failure message and will not know that the process/logic has been done.

How do I handle this?

Here are my thoughts on possible solutions:

- Leave existing behaviour, and if user complains then tech support can clarify that the process has gone through. Or error will alert support, and they will check the logs and contact the user to say it has gone through.

  - Leave the endpoint as idempotent (or similar ie no change in state of the app), so that the user can send the same request (with the same body) and get a response (when it is working ie no JsonProcessingException) which states it has already done it, or cannot do it as it has already done.
- Catch the JsonProcessingException when creating the json string, log it with exception message, and create a response without json informing the user that process has been done. Although this means the user will need to handle two different responses, but reduces human interaction in the above (current) solution.

  - OR convert/wrap it in a runtime exception (or other exception) and throw this in the catch block. But assign a better exception message (ie process was completed). Then in errorHandler, I can display this exception message in the response body, when it finds a specific exception. This way the user will know that the process was complete and not send another resquest. But as above, the user will have to handle to different types of responses.
- Do not use Jackson to create the json string, do it manually using String.format() and a json template. This is fine for simple json, but complex json will be a nightmare.
- Have some logic which checks if the previous call was done but not confirmed in the response, and then makes a call to the user (via some client ie email/sms) with correct details. Seems a lot of work.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Here is some example code to show where this is happening:

```java
private String createFailedResponseBodyJson(FailedPlaneLandStatus failedPlaneLandStatus) throws JsonProcessingException {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> jsonBody = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    jsonBody.put("PlaneId", failedPlaneLandStatus.planeId.value);
    jsonBody.put("PlaneStatus", failedPlaneLandStatus.planeStatus.name());
    jsonBody.put("AirportStatus", failedPlaneLandStatus.airportStatus.name());
    jsonBody.put("LandFailureReason", failedPlaneLandStatus.failureMessage.toString());

    return new ObjectMapper().setDefaultPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter())
            .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonBody);
}
```

It is the writeValueAsString() method which throws the JsonProcessingException

I think I am happy with the existing behaviour (First bullet point). But I just want to know if the other solutions (other bullet points) are viable, or if there is another solution?

Thanks

Comment: *How do I handle this?* by rollbacking the database transaction if an exception occurs? That said: why would transforming a Map<String, String> to a JSON string ever throw an exception?

Comment: Yes, it should not throw an exception with the inputs I provide( and control) to Jackson library. So I could just leave my code as is, and let any possible but remote exception bubble up.